# Find pattern from one file listed in another

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I want to find patterns that are listed in one file and find them in other file.
The second file has those patterns separated by commas.

for e.g. first file F1 has genes

```
ENSG00000187546
ENSG00000113492
ENSG00000166971
```

and second file F2 has those genes along with some more columns which I need

```
ENSG00000164252
ENSG00000187546
ENSG00000113492
ENSG00000166971,ENSG00000186106
```

So the gene ENSG00000166971 which is present in the second file does not show up in grep because it has another gene with it,separated by comma.

My code is:

```
  grep -f "F1.txt" "F2.txt" >output.txt
```

I want those values even if one of them is present,and the associated data with it.Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This is probably more on-topic at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to create the same situation.

[image]

getting ENSG00000166971 in the grep result.

may be this is due to different version.

i m using Fedora release 20 with grep 2.14.56-1e3d.